# set umask before every non login non interactive shell command

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, umask

I'm using PHP script to connect to ssh server. It executes one command and exit. Connection is made to non interactive and non login shell. Because of that it does not load `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files so I can't set proper `umask` there. I googled some information on ssh inner workings and it seems that I can use `~/.ssh/rc` file to execute some commands after ssh connection. My `~/.ssh/rc` **on server** I am connecting:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Setting umask to 002"
umask 002
echo "Umask set"
```

The problem is that my umask is not set properly. When I run my script and it run `umask` command on server, I get `0022` umask :

```
Run: cd /local/web/ && umask
> Setting umask to 002
> Umask set
> 0022
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Surely you mean `~/.ssh/rc` not `~/.ss/rc`, if not then that may be part of your issue. Otherwise [here is an answer on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/q/228396/310481).

Comment: Yes, it was typo, I fixed it. Your link with  `pam_umask` is probably correct solution. But I'm curious why `umask` does not work inside my server `~/.ssh/rc`  file  since `echo` commands are executed.

Comment: [Check the man page for sshd](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd&sec=8) - in the SSHRC section it specifically states _It must not produce any output on stdout; stderr must be used instead._ maybe that is your issue.

Comment: [Here's Stack Overflow Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17228798/3448214) where it is commented that the SSHRC method does not work - although no reason why not.

Comment: I also tried putting only `umask 002 &>/dev/null` inside `~/.ssh/rc` but it does not work either, like in SO question from your comment above. I'll try use `pam_umask` or some server script to fix permissions. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

`umask` only works if it is run by a builtin command.

Do not call the script by name but rather call `. script` to let it be executed by the current shell process.

If you however are confused by the value printed as `0022`instead of `022`, there os no difference, these values are identical.

Try the POSIX `umask -S` to get a better understandable output.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you telling me. Should I create another script beside `~/.ssh/rc` and source it inside? How is it different from just calling `umask` directly inside `~/.ssh/rc` on ssh server? This file is executed by ssh on  connect. `echo` commands are executed then why not `umask`?